# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

This problem occurred when i was trying to generate a database through a [model](http://imgur.com/X4LnEGd)

i tried to resolve some isolated issues like mySQL56 not running properly by re-adding it to the tray

i also have the updated prerequisites for mysql, namely:
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.1
the Connector/Net 6.9.6 product.

i also tried to update and add the references via Nuget

```
MySql.Data 6.9.6
MySql.Data.Entities 6.8.3.0
MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.6
MySql.Fabric 6.9.6
MySQL.Net 6.6.4
MySql.Web
```

but i am still getting error... did i miss something? In my Web.Config:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data><MySQL>
```